# What are the reasons to delete a question?

Tags: support, etiquette, vote-to-delete

Ok I read [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/186423) and still don't know what are possible reasons to delete a question. When there is an article about [What is a “closed” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10582/186423) it nicely gives the reasons. I ask to do the same for deletion status.

To be more precise (after the edit):
I have a problem with a *question asked by a mistake*. I see it is not mentioned in "reasons for closing", so I think maybe it is included in "reasons for deletion". So I look for those reasons. By a *question asked by a mistake* I mean a question like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582774/xpath-expression-fails-libxml2-in-c/12584251#12584251), that is: *why the feature XXX of YYY fails in this case?*. After answers or suggestions the asker decides that it was his mistake and the question actually is useless for the community.

Comment: What precisely do you feel is missing from that FAQ? What needs to be addressed? Because as your question is phrased now, you run the risk of it being closed as a dupe of that very FAQ.

Comment: Are you asking what are the reasons a post gets deleted by moderators, or what are the reasons you might want to delete your own question?

Comment: All closed questions are candidates for deletion. Deletion occurs when question are off-topic mostly.

Comment: I explained in edit that I want to ask meta about "questions asked by a mistake", but first wanted to know more about "deletion".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion):

> Questions that are extremely off topic, or of very low quality, may be removed at the discretion of the community and moderators.
>
> Over time, closed questions that are not useful as signpoints to other questions may also be removed, as well as questions which have no significant activity over a very long period after being asked. For additional guidance, see How to Ask.
>
> Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are …
>
> - commentary on the question or other answers
> - asking another, different question
> - “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
> - exact duplicates of other answers
> - barely more than a link to an external site
> - not even a partial answer to the actual question

The specific question you linked to should probably be closed as Too Localized and deleted, it's extremely unlikely that someone else will face the same problem in the future.

Comment: May I expect the faq be updated as a direct edition of the answer to [*How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/186423) or tagging this one with *faq*?

Comment: @jarekczek We have two FAQs, the site FAQ (where I got the quote from) and Meta questions tagged [faq]. The site FAQ is the primary (or perhaps the short) version, and the information you were looking for is right there, no need to duplicate it in the secondary (or additional) version.

Comment: In fiction it is good to use different words, but not in faqs I guess :) When I go to the main faq and search for "delet" I get nothing. But in general you are right and I could find what I was looking for in main Faq. Thanks for making it clear for me.

Comment: @jarekczek For some reason the FAQ uses "removed" instead of "deleted", although deleted is what I'd look for as well, it's far more commonly used within the community than removed. For example, we have delete votes, not remove votes.